# How do I install PS3 Game Utility for Dead Island

Tags: ps3, dead-island

I haven't played Dead Island for a few days so I missed the release of the new patch over the last weekend. So when I tried to play with my buddies I obviously couldn't because of version differences. I tried to delete the game utility from my HDD, but when I opened up the utility folder, the file for Dead Island wasn't there! Strangely enough I'm still able to play the game and will get auto saves form time to time. Is there any way I can install the new patch from an outside source other than auto update? Because it seems that whenever I try to play, there is no prompt to update and I can't find a way to do it from the game.

Comment: Have you updated your PS3's System Software recently? There was an update just recently, and PSN doesn't cooperate until you install it.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it is to back up all your DI files to a USB, then delete them from your PS3. Then boot up the game, install the patch, and then put your save data back in.

Comment: Welcome to Gaming! If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.